# Keras/TensorFlow: How do I transform text to use as input?

Tags: file-io, tensorflow, keras

I've been reading tutorials for the last few days, but they all seem to start at the step of "I have my data from this pre-prepared data set, let's go".

What I'm trying to do is take a set of emails I've tokenized, and figure out how to get them into a model as the training and evaluation data.

Example email:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 32192 6675 16943 1380 433 8767 2254 8869 8155
```

I have a folder of emails (one file per email) for each spam and not spam:

```
/spam/
    93451.txt
    ...
/not-spam/
    112.txt
    ...
```

How can I get Keras to read this data?

Alternatively, how can I generate a CSV or some other format that it wants to use to input it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood from your task description (please guide me if I'm wrong), you need to classify texts into either spam or not spam category.
Basically, if you want to create the universal text data classification input solution, your 
data input stage code should contain 3 steps:
1. Reading list of folders ("spam", "not spam" in your case) and iterating each folder to the list of files. 
At the end you should have: 
a) a dictionary containing (`label_id -> label_name`). 
So in your case, you should stay with (`0-> spam, 1->not_spam`). 
b) A pair of (file_content, label).
As you understand, this is out of scope of both keras and tensorflow. It is typical python' code. 
2. For each part (file_content, label) you should process the first element, and that's the most interesting part usually. 
In your example I can see `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 32192 6675 16943 1380 433 8767 2254 8869 8155`.
 So you already have the indexes of the words, but they are in the text form. All you need is to transform the string to the array having the 300 items (words in your message). 
For the further text machine learning projects, I suggest to use raw text data as a source and transform it to the word indexes using `tf.contrib.learn.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor`. 
3. Transform labels(categories) to the `one-hot` vector.
So at the end of these step you have a pair of (`word_indexes_as_array, label_as_one_hot`).
Then you can use these data as input data for training.
Naturally, you would divide this tuple into two, treating the first 80% of data as training set and 20% as testing set (please do not focus on 80/20, numbers it is just a sample).
You may look at at the [text classification with keras](https://github.com/keon/keras-text-classification) examples. They are rather straightforward and may be helpful for you as they are starting from the [data input step](https://github.com/keon/keras-text-classification/blob/master/data_helpers.py).
Also, please, look at the `load_data_and_labels()` method in the [data input step](https://github.com/keon/keras-text-classification/blob/master/data_helpers.py) example. It is a very similar case to yours (positive/negative).

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, but ill try in this order:

1. You need to create dictionary of all the words in dataset and then assign a token for each of them. When inputing to the network you can convert it into a `one-hot` encoded form.
2. You can convert the input text by feeding it to a pretrained `word embeddings model` like `glove` or `word-2-vec` and obtain a `embeddings` vector.
3. You can use the `one-hot` vector from 1 and train your own `embeddings`.

Comment: I have tokenized the words. The problem I have is I don't know what format to put the data into, or how to actually get it into the script. I looked up one-hot, but that also doesn't help me.
Do I generate a CSV with a column containing the label, and a column containing the text, or a csv with one col for each of the 300 words in the email, or something else? Can I just tell it to read each file by itself?

Comment: In your CSV, each input (email) should have a column `label` and a 300 columns containing the tokenised words.